# Appmenu indicator places drop down duplicates nautilus bookmarks

Tags: indicator, appmenu

On the 'Places' drop down menu of the appmenu indicator applet, the list of nautilus bookmarks seems to be duplicated, it keeps repeating all of the bookmarks, so that places menu is very big. Its only a minor annoyance but is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this might be [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appmenu-gtk/+bug/655241) and the fix should be coming in an update.

Answer (score 1):

It is something that bug me too.
I resolved by manually removing ( i.e. delete ) the duplicates from nautilus.

Open Nautilus, select the place from the sidebar, hit [Delete]

Comment: There not duplicated in nautilus though, if i delete them from there, they get removed entirely from the appmenu applet.

Comment: Sorry, mine gets duplicated in Nautilus too.